# Access violation writing location error

Tags: c++, access-violation

I'm suffering some access violation. I'm writing simple program, working like a database.

`First-chance exception at 0x00088AB6 in kasia2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.
Unhandled exception at 0x00088AB6 in kasia2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.`

Problem occurs when trying to do this step second time in a row.

```
 cout << "Podaj autora: ";
 cin.sync();
 getline(cin, d[il].autor);
 cout << "Podaj tytul: ";
 cin.sync();
 getline(cin, d[il].tytul);
 cout << "Podaj date wydania: ";
 cin >> d[il].data;
```

And here is a structure I work at and memory allocation.

```
struct Ksiazka
{
    string autor;
    string tytul;
    int data;
};

struct Ksiazka * d = new Ksiazka;
```

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: When you single-step it with the debugger, which line excepts?

Comment: What is the value of `il` when it crashes? You are accessing `d` as if it was an array, while you initialized it as only one element.

Comment: You're using `d` as though it is an array, wheras it is a single object. This could possibly work if `il` is zero, but shouldn't be relied upon, and is Undefined Behaviour. What is the value of `il`? I guess it's zero the first time through.

Comment: @Enigma uncanny resemblance in our answers (c:

Comment: @Peter Wood: Great minds think alike =o)

Comment: @Enigma Although, beware the [Confirmation Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) (c:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `d[il].autor`, if `il` is not exactly `0`, you will access memory that you haven't allocated. `0xCDCDCDCD` is one of the Microsoft "fill patterns" for unused memory, so this appears to be the case.

If you want multiple sets of `Ksiazka`, then you should do something like:

```
struct Ksiazka * d = new Ksiazka[x];
```

where `x` i the number you want.

Or, particularly if you don't know how many you actually "need", use `std::vector`, and something like this:

```
 std::vector<Ksiazka> d;`

 ... 

 Ksiazaka tmp;
 cout << "Podaj autora: ";
 cin.sync();
 getline(cin, tmp.autor);
 cout << "Podaj tytul: ";
 cin.sync();
 getline(cin, tmp.tytul);
 cout << "Podaj date wydania: ";
 cin >> tmp.data;
 d.push_back(tmp);
```